# PostgreSQL distance between 2 points stored in table

Tags: postgresql

I have four fields lat1,lng1,lat2,lng2 and I would like to calculate the distance in km between them (rounded to 1 deciaml place).

For example
table:

```
-----lat1-----|--- lng1 ----| ----lat2----|---lng2----|
 53.4603045   |  9,98243    |  53,4470272 | 9,9956593 |
```

I have tried:

```
   SELECT ST_Distance(POINT(lat1, lng1),POINT(lat2, lng2)) as distance FROM table
```

What do I have to change?

Comment: what're you trying to achieve with this function call?

Comment: I'm trying to calculate the distance between those two points

Comment: how did you define ST_Distance function? Do you have postgis installed?

Comment: I thought that that was a standart PostgreSQL function

Comment: PostGIS is not part of a standard Postgres distribution. You need to install manually as an extensioin: http://postgis.net/install

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostGIS is the answer.

I'll give it a go

Answer (score 0):

If your postgres comes with plv8 extension (javascript), you can do something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION distance_example(_la integer, _lb integer) RETURNS
real AS $$

  var locations = plv8.execute("SELECT * FROM location WHERE id IN ($1, $2)", [_la, _lb]);
  var x = locations[0].longitude - locations[1].longitude;
  var y = locations[0].latitude - locations[1].latitude;
  return Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
$$ LANGUAGE plv8 IMMUTABLE STRICT;

select distance_example();
```