# How I calculate the total distance of points in postgres in a table?

Tags: postgresql

```
long,lat,time
10,11,0
11,12,1
12,13,2
```

I have a simple table with longitudine, latitude and time and i want know a function that calculate the total distance of points in postgres.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PostgreSQL distance between 2 points stored in table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18918919/postgresql-distance-between-2-points-stored-in-table)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to calculate the distance you can use the extention earthdistance and do something like :

```
SELECT earth_distance(lat, long)
  FROM your_table;
```

The earthdistance module provides two different approaches to calculating great circle distances on the surface of the Earth. The one described first depends on the cube package (which must be installed before earthdistance can be installed). The second one is based on the built-in point datatype, using longitude and latitude for the coordinates.

In this module, the Earth is assumed to be perfectly spherical. (If that's too inaccurate for you, you might want to look at the PostGIS project.)